# What are the alternative titles of Thayodhamma Sutta, it's reference number, subsections where it appear in?

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon, sutras

I am looking Thayodhamma Sutta but could not find it based on the following searchers: accesstoinsight.org [search on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Thayodhamma%20Sutta%20site%3Aaccesstoinsight.org), suttacentral.net [search on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Thayodhamma+Sutta+site:suttacentral.net). But references do turn up in a [general Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Thayodhamma%20Sutta).

Is it possible to give the Alternative titles of the Sutta, Sutta reference number and link to the Sutta or subsections in which appear in?

I think this Sutta maybe know by a different title on some of these sites which is why it is not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thayodhamma sutta (Abandon three things at a time).  [The Discourse on the Three Things (Regarding Incapability)](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/2.4-Abhabba-Tayodhamma-S-a10.76-piya_bk1.pdf)

To abandon…  1. Birth;  2. Old age;  3. Death

You have to abandon…   1. Greed (passion);  2. Hatred;  3. Delusion

To abandon the above three you have to abandon…  1. Personality view;   2. Doubt;   3. Rituals and observances.

To abandon the above three you have to abandon…  1. Drowsiness of the mind;   2. Following the wrong path;   3. Unwise attention

To abandon the above three you have to abandon…   1. Unmindfulness (wrong mindfulness);   2. Unawareness;   3. Mental distraction.

To abandon the above three you have to abandon…  1. Dislike to see the noble ones;   2. Dislike to hear the noble teachings;   3. Fault-finding mind;

To abandon the above three you have to abandon…  1. Conceit;  2. Unrestraint;   3. Immorality

To abandon the above three you have to abandon….  1. Lack of confidence;  2. Dislike to listen to others;   3. Laziness

To abandon the above three you have to abandon…  1. Unfriendliness;  2. Disobedience;   3. Bad Friends (Asathpurisa Sevanaya)

To abandon the above three you have to abandon…  1. Shamelessness;   2. Fearlessness;   3. Non-diligence.

A Sotāpanna (Pali) or "He who entered(āpanna) the stream(sota)." ‘stream” is a metaphor for the third of the Four Noble Truths, Noble Eightfold Path. A stream which rigidly flows will not stop until it enters the sea. A Sotapanna has completely entered in to the Eight fold Noble Dhamma Path(Has gained the first magga-phala). So he will surely achieve Arhathood within seven births that are born in human and heavenly happy realms and his spiritual development will not descend.

Attainment

Sotapanna is a person who has eliminated the first three bondages (sanyojanas) from the mind.

Those are,

1. Strong ego or Personality view(sakkaya dhitti)
2. Doubt(Wichikiccha)
3. Wrong rituals and observances/ Superstitions(Seelabbatha paramasa)

Thayodhamma sutta(Abandon three things at a time) explains the skills that should be developed to achieve this supreme task.